# Passing function name as param to another function not working javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an class called `myObject`, which has multiple methods, one of which is `add`. I am using another function with an argument for which function of `myObject` I want to use. If I want to use `add`, I pass it 'add.' If I want to use `delete`, I'd pass it 'delete,' etc. In the definition of the function `test`, if I use `obj.add` it works fine, but if I use `obj.func`, the passed parameter, it doesn't work. I tested to make sure `func = add`, and it is, but for some reason it won't work with the parameter. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
testObj = new myObject();
test(testObj, 'add', 3);


function test(obj, func, parm){
     var answer = obj.func(parm);
}
```

Comment: Use bracket notation `obj[func](param)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way objects work in javascript. `obj.func` will try to run a function in obj called `func`. However if you remember that all objects in javascript are functions. Then you can do this: `obj[func]` which will evaluate the funct variable and look for the method in obj with that evaluated name.

```
testObj = new myObject();
test(testObj, 'add', 3);


function test(obj, func, parm){
     var answer = obj[func](parm);
}
```